# Div id inside javascript new google.maps.LatLng

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code for Detect ip from location using google map the problem is how do i set  `new google.maps.LatLng('< HERE >') to <div id="loc"></div>` ? which result is **40.4652,-74.2307** part of #loc

```js
<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng('<div id="loc"></div>'),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<Script>
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/104.238.132.170/json", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#loc").html("" + response.loc);
    $("#region").html("" + response.region);
    $("#country").html("" + response.country);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
</script>
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract latitude an longitude

```
 [lat,lng] = $("#loc").html().split(',').map(parseFloat);
```

and pass them to google.maps.LatLng

```
var mapProp= {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
```

Comment: where to put  [lat,lng] = $("#loc").html().split(',').map(parseFloat);? on javascript part? it not work

Comment: somewhere after the `$get` ajax call has completed successfully. You can also update the map with [map.setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: it didnt work.. but i have edit to     $lag = $("#loc").html("" + response.loc); and    center: new google.maps.LatLng('$lag'), it show me grey map with hand cursor before it was white page